# Can I Reinstall Application Loader Without Xcode?

Tags: applications, xcode, app-store-connect

I just became an Apple Developer about an hour ago. On another question I was advised that I could use Application Loader to submit my Unity 3D puzzle apps to the Mac App Store. I read that it was included in Xcode. I have the latest version of Xcode installed but I cannot get it to work. When I log in it says that I don't have the proper contracts signed in iTunes Connect.

I decided to try and open Application Loader from the Applications folder. It had the white symbol of an invalid application. When I clicked it the message said that it was either corrupted or was incomplete. I deleted the application since it was worthless.

After more research this [documentation](http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdATD1E927-D1E1A1303-D1E927A1126) said that I could download it in iTunes Connect. I don't have a My Apps icon in my iTunes Connect account.

I'm an Apple Developer so I don't understand what contracts I have to sign at this point. I'm thinking that the problem was with the Application Loader application. I cannot find a link where I can download the dmg file to reinstall this. I could not find where I could reinstall Xcode which includes Application Loader from what I have read. I'm concerned about uninstalling Xcode since I have started an online course using it.

Can I install Application Loader by itself?

Comment: Before you upload any apps, you should go to the Apple Developer Member Center (developer.apple.com) and make sure you've completed all the bank and tax documents you need to file.  The majority of developers I know don't use Application Loader to upload their apps, they just do it with Xcode (myself included).

Comment: Application Loader is one of the developer tools included in Xcode-->Open Developer Tool. It was suggested for apps not created in Xcode where I could upload to iTunes Connect directly somehow. I tried to find where I could update my bank and tax documents but there was not a section available on the developer website. I just noticed that I have not received my activation email. I have my bank and tax info in iTunes Connect.

Comment: I know what Application Loader is and where it's located, thanks.  iTunes Connect is part of the Member Center.  To download it, in Xcode go to Xcode --> Open Developer Tool --> Application Loader.